# Обособление определения, стоящего после определяемого слова

Tags: пунктуация, определения

[Из Фармакопеи РФ (ГФ РФ 13)](http://pharmacopoeia.ru/gosudarstvennaya-farmakopeya-xiii-online-gf-13-online/ofs-1-1-0006-15-farmatsevticheskie-substantsii/):

> Для субстанций, **представляющих собой стандартизованную смесь биологически активных веществ растительного или животного происхождения** возможны отклонения от данных требований или дополнительные требования, указанные в фармакопейных статьях.

Интересно, почему выделенное определение, стоящее после определяемого слова, обособлено запятой только с одной стороны. Это недочет составителей, или запятая после "происхождения" не обязательна?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, это недочет составителей. Здесь деепричастный оборот, он должен выделяться запятыми.